# XCUITest is matching descendent elements from another parent, instead of the one I am looking at

Tags: ios, xcode, xcuitest

lets say I have 2 views, A and B, under the same application window.

View A has a staticText element with identifier "Identifier_String" while B does not;

However, when I use:

```
[[[section-B descendantsMatchingType:XCUIElementTypeStaticText] matchingIdentifier:@"Identifier_String"] firstMatch];
```

it is able to find a match and returns the staticText under section-A...

Answer (score 0):

Probably the B view is descendant of the A view. You should check your accessibility hierarchy with `print(app.debugDescription)` and create a new query. Also, you may use `children` instead of `descendants` if it is appropriate for your needs.